# can't put a document on cloudant with curl

Tags: php, curl, cloudant

In php, I have this working :

```
$results = shell_exec('c:/xamppp/apache/bin/curl -X POST 
"https://xxx:xxx@xxx.cloudant.com/essai" -d {} -H "Content-Type: 
application/json"');
```

It works and a blank document appears in cloudant. But when I try :

```
{"toto":"123"}
```

to insert a non empty doc, it fails ({"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"})

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the contents for -d in single quotes (escaped since your calling the command with single quotes):

```
-d \'{"toto": "123"}\'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it !